# After recent sublime text update cursor is extra tall and doesnt blink

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

My cursor height is stuck at what appears to be the max height of the line and its padding/margin, nor does it blink anymore. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p5JI.png). What settings should I look at to get this sorted out?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Search in the left side of the Settings window for `caret`. That should get you to the right group of settings. I have the following set:

```json
// These settings control the size of the caret
"caret_extra_bottom": 0,
"caret_extra_top": 0,
"caret_extra_width": 0,

// Valid values are "smooth", "phase", "blink" and "solid". Previous
// versions of Sublime Text used "smooth" by default.
"caret_style": "smooth"
```

and it looks pretty similar to ST3.

Comment: The defaults for ST3 are `2` and `2` for the extra top/bottom, but both are `4` in ST~~4~~ to make the cursor more visible with `caret_style` changing to `solid`; this is of course down to personal preference.

Comment: I think default was `0` `1` `1` and `smooth`.